# Achieving iOS 7.1 UINavigationBar blur

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, blur, ios7.1

I have another `UIView` under the navigation bar like this.

[image]

I want the slight blur of the navigation bar for that `UIView` too. Currently I have its alpha value reduced but it doesn't give the desired effect as you can see.

How can I get the frosty look of the navigation bar for the `UIView` as well? I'm on iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `UIView` - you will never achieve a consistent result with the navigation bar.

Use a `UIToolbar` and place it below the navigation bar. Set the delegate of the toolbar to your view controller and implement `positionForBar:` to return `UIBarPositionTop` or `UIBarPositionTopAttached`. You can then add all the subviews you have in your view to the toolbar.

Comment: Great! I didn't know that. Much more elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @leo-natan, do you have some sample code? Is this doable at application wide level via AppDelegate?

Comment: @Dean If you wish to have a consistent view under your navigation bar, I would suggest subclassing `UINavigationBar` and doing the magic in `viewWillLayout`/`viewDidLayout` by resizing the content view and adding a toolbar as discussed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UIToolbar`, it's the quickest way.
If you want to customize it, you have to use 3rd library like `ILTrasparentView`, `FXBlurView` ...